# How to generate string combinations by replacement characters

Tags: c#

Raising this question to find out how to solve this riddle in C#. It is a chracter replacement in a way that will generate combinations that are possible after the replacement. The target string that ought to have characters replaced is "?-?" where the question mark is always the character needs to the replaced by either an "x" or "&". When the replacement has been done the output ( for "?-?" ) should be:

"x-x"
"x-&"
"&-&"
"&-x"

I am looking for a generalised C# algorithm that can generate string combinations for similar string patterns. For example: inputting "?-" should generate "x-" and "&-"

Comment: What code have you written so far?

Comment: If you share where you get an error about the code in my article, we need to help the size.

Comment: @sr28, no code has been written so far.

Comment: You might want to give it a go first and see how you get on. If you come up with some specific issues then come back here. However, Stack Overflow isn't a code writing service, so many people will just ignore questions where the person hasn't even attempted it first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```cs
string table = "?-?";
char[] substitutionCandidates = { '?' }; // Can be expanded
string[] successorChars = { "&", "x" }; // Can be expanded and contain multi-char strings

List<string> combinations = new List<string> { "" };

for (int i = 0; i < table.Length; i++)
    combinations = !substitutionCandidates.Contains(table[i])
        ? combinations.Select(x => x + table[i]).ToList()
        : combinations.SelectMany(x => successorChars.Select(y => x + y)).ToList();


// Usage:
foreach (var x in combinations)
    Console.WriteLine(x);

// Output:
// &-&
// &-x
// x-&
// x-x
```

Description:

- [`Enumerable.Select`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=netcore-3.1) Method: Projects each element of a sequence into a new form.
- [`Enumerable.SelectMany`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany?view=netcore-3.1) Method: Projects each element of a sequence to an IEnumerable and flattens the resulting sequences into one sequence.
- [`Enumerable.ToList`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.tolist?view=netcore-3.1) Method: Creates a List from an IEnumerable.

---

Don't forget `using System.Linq;` and `using System.Collections.Generic;`.